# JS with select boxes

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a bit of javascript that will execute when a checkbox is checked.

When the checkbox is checked, the form will display 2 more select boxes.

I've attempted something but i'm not very good with javascript, can someone take a look and lemme know where i'm going wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#repeat").change(function () {
        if ($("#repeat").checked){
            $("#numbers").slideDown();
        } else{
            $("#numbers").slideUp();
        }
    });
    $("#numbers").hide();
    $("#repeat").tigger("change");
});
```

And the id of the checkbox is repeat and id of one of the select boxes is numbers.

Comment: protip: `if (this.checked) { ... }`

Comment: Should `tigger` be `trigger`, or were you referencing a fictional tiger?

Comment: So what's your relevant HTML? [dsfq's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22797267/82548) looks like it should work, so what's stopping it, HTML elements, typos, conflicting JavaScript, errors in the browser console?

Answer (score 0):

This part is not correct:

```
$("#repeat").checked
```

and should be

```
this.checked
```

So whole script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#repeat").change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $("#numbers").slideDown();
        } else {
            $("#numbers").slideUp();
        }
    });
    $("#numbers").hide();
    $("#repeat").trigger("change"); // <--- trigger, not tigger
});
```

`$("#repeat")` is a jQuery instance object, it doesn't have a property `checked`. However `this` inside of change event handler refers to the HTMLSelectElement which has this property.

Also it's `trigger` not `tigger`.

Comment: still won't do anything, doesn't even hide the select.

Comment: @AnujHari It also should be `trigger` not `tigger`.

Comment: I've done the trigger thing, but it still won't hide or do anything.

Comment: Can you set up a demo?

Comment: I didn't see your actual code so I don't know. Check developer console, maybe there are some errors.